# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am new in php i am getting this error while updating one of the column of the table

```
    if(isset($_POST['approved'])) {
    $change="SELECT * FROM `workplan`";
    $forchange=mysql_query($change);

    while ($infoChange = mysql_fetch_array($forchange)) {
        $dep=$infoChange['division name']
        mysql_query("UPDATE workplan SET status= ['0'] WHERE  month=['january']");

    }
}
```

i only one to update the column of status to the value from 1 to 0 from 13 colums ..

Comment: Just saying consider switching to `mysqli` or `pdo` - default `mysql_query()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5

Comment: @Kevin Pei: no dynamic parts in these queries though

Comment: @zerkms thanks, I've updated my comment. It's still deprecated though :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon:

```
$dep=$infoChange['division name'] <--HERE
```

Comment: unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in - whenever you see `unexpected ....` it means you have normally not close a brace or added a semi-colon at the end of a line. +1 for the quick spot John

Comment: @user3480212: nope - `SET status= ['0']` <- what's this?

Comment: for updaing the value of status column value to 0 @zerkms

Comment: @user3480212: where did you find such a syntax?

Comment: through internet @zerkms can you help me out how to do it please

Comment: @user3480212: Get rid of the square braces.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to find these types of errors in code but this error only occurs when you miss some type of symbol in code.

I also stuck in that error

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'sorry' (T_STRING)**
and  removing this by just addining " into my code

before adding (**"**) this

```
 $sql = "select * from user_profiles where email = '$email';
```

afetr adding (**"**)

```
$sql = "select * from user_profiles where email = '$email'";
```